# How to check wordpress user auth in Laravel?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, integration, easy-digital-downloads

I have a `Wordpress` site with 10000 users. I use `EDD` for shopping system. now I want to make a ticketing system with `Laravel`.

- example.com         ---> My Shop (WP v5.x & EDD)
- support.example.com ---> Support System (Laravel v6.5.x)

I have already change the Worpdress cookie path to enable access wp cookies in subdomains,
but I don't know how to check a user is logged in or get product data (EDD) from wp in laravel backend?

Comment: somebody can help?